# WCF service: how to handle null-values for DataMembers?

Tags: wcf, null

I have, without any luck, been googling for some time now trying to find out how a WCF service reacts to null values - both directly as in the actual parameter of the service method is set to null; as well indirectly: any property of the parameter (DataContract-annotated object) is null.

Should my service perform null checks on any property value it accesses or is this somehow implicit? In case my service method performs a call on a null-property, will this simply result in a `FaultException` (without any information on what went wrong) being passed to the client?

Regards

Comment: I tend to handle this like on any local object. If the parameter or a property can be `null`, I check for `null`. The only thing I've noticed is that for streamed methods (when the method returns a stream), `null` can not be returned (or I didn't do it properly). I had to return an empty stream and had to check whether the stream contained any data. In your case, it could help to modify the service configuration so that error information is passed to the client to get information on the real cause of the exception.

Comment: That really totally depends on what your service can do. It might very well be that a NULL is a valid parameter value - then your service code has to deal with it whichever way is "right". Or it could be a non-acceptable value, then your service code should raise a `FaultException`, for sure.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Thank you for your comment. If possible, I would very much like to avoid these excessive checks in every service method since it gets very ugly.
If the client attempts to submit invalid data, it is the client's own fault (since validity checks should be performed on the client). However, I am in doubt if it would crash my server in case I try to do a call to an object that is null, or is this parsed on to the client (wrapped in a FaultException)?

Comment: @marc_s: Basically no parameter nor parameter-property should be null. Is there any way to specify this in the DataContract rather than having to deal with it in every single service method (checking for nulls and setting up FaultExceptions)?

Comment: For data members, yes, you can define this with: `[DataMember(IsRequired=True)]`. I don't think there's any "out-of-the-box" solution for checking simple parameters - you *could* write your own parameter inspector (deriving from  `IParameterInspector`) and make it so it could be applied as an attribute on your operations - but that would be an advanced exercise in WCF extensibility :-)

Comment: @jvmk: See my answer below. Looking through some code I noticed that I'm not doing excessive `null` checks. In most of my services, I'm using database connections. I'm not doing anything special, but I'm returning SQL Exceptions to the client, so that I can display a message like *Service method failed: Could not connect to database* or something like that.

Comment: Also check out [this other SO question on parameter inspection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812187/wcf-parameter-validation-with-interceptor) - might be helpful

Comment: @marc_s: Thank you very much, that will actually do very well. With this approach I will only have to check the actual parameters and not all "sub parameters" (i.e. properties of the actual parameters) for nulls. With regards to the other SO question you guided me to: That is basically just an alternative to explicit null checks at the start of each method, right?

Comment: @marc_s: 
A final question with regards to exceptions in the WCF service: When I throw a FaultException, does the service method terminate? When I run my service method in debug mode, it seems that I can actually get further after having thrown a FaultException.
Thanks again, you have been very helpful.

Comment: A FaultException terminates the program flow like any other exception you throw. Sure there isn't any exception handler or `finally` block involved that causes additional code to run?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: There are try-catch blocks further down the service method code - but these do not catch FaultExceptions and more importantly they are at the same nesting as the throw statement :-). Must be the debugger that can force code to proceed.

Comment: Typically, a WCF service is a "per-call" affair: each incoming request from a client gets a new instance of the service class, that instance handles the requested method, and then terminates anyway. So there's really no difference. Throwing a FaultException also leaves the communications channel between client and service intact - so you should be good on all fronts, really.

Answer (score 1):

I turned on error reporting in my service configuration to return useful error information to the client:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="errorEnabledBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/> <!-- THIS IS IT! -->
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Make sure to use this behavior in your service definition

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="errorEnabledBehavior" ...>
```

**EDIT**
I'm using this in a local environment where I log errors on the server side anyway including a full stack trace. As the OP mentioned in his comment, passing this information to the client may be dangerous and should not be used in a production environment. Another solution would be to use a custom fault contract as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294609/Uing-FaultContract-to-throw-custom-error-informati).

Comment: I know of this approach, but I read that error information should NOT be parsed to the client like this in production code - it's only for development debugging.
Edit: I read this useful [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294609/Uing-FaultContract-to-throw-custom-error-informati) article that teaches how to inform the client of errors in WCF.

Comment: OK, in our case this really doesn't matter too much, as both clients and services are running in a local network and we're logging the exceptions on the server side anyways :-) The article you linked, however, does provide a proper way of returning the errors to the client. Even though a "catch all" exception handler isn't too nice either, you could use that to fill your custom error object.

Comment: I see :-). Thank you for taking your time to share your experience in this matter.