# get RAW XML also of malformed XML syntax calls

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I create a simple DispatchMessageInspector.
The problem is that the inspector is not called when XML is malformed.
It is possible to get RAW XML also of malformed XML syntax calls ?

```
public class WcfMessageDebugger : IDispatchMessageInspector, IServiceBehavior
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Log4net logger
    /// </summary>
    private ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public WcfMessageDebugger(ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }

    object IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        if (Logger != null)
        {
            var textMessage = request.ToString();

            // HERE NOT PASS WHEN XML IS MALFORMED

            Logger.Debug(textMessage);
        }
        return null;
    }

    void IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        if (Logger != null)
        {                
            Logger.Debug(reply.ToString());
        }
    }      

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    { 
        // non necessario  
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (var endpoint in dispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                var debugger = new WcfMessageDebugger(Logger);
                endpoint.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(debugger);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {            
    }
}
```

I also changed the option in web.config without results

```
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging
       logEntireMessage="true"
       logMalformedMessages="true"
       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
</diagnostics>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What do you mean "no result" when you added the `<diagnostics>`? Do you get other logging, but not the message logging?

Comment: I mean that there is no change and the malformed xml is not passed to the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'd have to do it as an IIS Module.  Write a custom HTTP module that will catch all the exceptions and then have the module react when it comes across malformed XML.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913544/wcf-400-bad-request-when-object-properties-are-incorrect/23022072#23022072) SO question that I answered about how to do that.

Comment: the problem is that, for usability reasons, I need to log every call to the webservice with Data-In + Some data of the operation service + Data-Out together on the same raw of the logger. If I create a HTTP module I think I need to log the calls separated from the webservice results and I can't read together on the same row of the logger. It is true ?

Comment: Right, you can't update a log's rows.  If that was the requirement, I would switch to a database solution so you can create / update records as they are recorded.