# WCF parameter validation using IParameterInspector and handle FaultException at client

Tags: iphone, wcf, validation, rest, parameters

I'm having a WCF Rest service which does input parameter validation by using the `IParameterInspector`, before calling the actual service method. Now these rest services are consumed by iPhone. If parameter is not valid then i have thrown faultexception which i want to handle at iPhone (or may be Android) side. 
Well i have refer so many links in stackoverflow and i have used below link as reference in my code.

[WCF Parameter Validation with Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812187/wcf-parameter-validation-with-interceptor)
Following is my step-by-step code snippet.

=> FaultExceptionResponse class which is used in `FaultException<T>`

```
[DataContract]
public class FaultExceptionResponse
{
        [DataMember]
        public bool Success { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ResponseString { get; set; }
}
```

=> Below class validate parameters.

```
public class ValidationParameterInspectorAttribute : Attribute, IParameterInspector, IOperationBehavior
    {

        public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
        {
        }

        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            if (operationName == "GetCommunicationDetailById")
            {
                var communicationChatViewModel = inputs.FirstOrDefault() as CommunicationChatViewModel;

                if (communicationChatViewModel != null &&
                    (communicationChatViewModel.iConsultCommunicationID <= 0))
                {
                    //ErrorLogger.LogErrorMessageToElmah(new ArgumentException("API Name: GetCommunicationDetailById   Parameter cannot be less than zero.", "iConsultCommunicationID"));
                    var fc = new FaultExceptionResponse { Success = false, ResponseString = "Invalid parameter found while fetching communication detail !" };
                    throw new FaultException<FaultExceptionResponse>(fc, new FaultReason(fc.ResponseString));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
        }
    }
```

=> and then i have decorate my API like this

```
[OperationContract]
[ValidationParameterInspector]
[FaultContract(typeof(FaultExceptionResponse))]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/GetCommunicationDetailById")]
 CommunicationChatDetailList GetCommunicationDetailById(CommunicationChatViewModel communicationParaViewModel);
```

Everything works fine but when parameter is not valid then this faultException thrown at iPhone side, it shows only below error information.

```
Error: {
    AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey = "<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7faa605faa90> { URL: http://192.168.151.40/MyWCF/Service1.svc/GetCommunicationDetailById } { status code: 400, headers {\n    \"Cache-Control\" = private;\n    \"Content-Length\" = 3319;\n    \"Content-Type\" = \"text/html\";\n    Date = \"Fri, 25 Sep 2015 15:45:14 GMT\";\n    Server = \"Microsoft-IIS/7.5\";\n    \"X-AspNet-Version\" = \"4.0.30319\";\n    \"X-Powered-By\" = \"ASP.NET\";\n} }";
    NSErrorFailingURLKey = "http://192.168.151.40/MyWCF/Service1.svc/GetCommunicationDetailById";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Request failed: bad request (400)";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 \"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html\" UserInfo={AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7faa605faa90> { URL: http://192.168.151.40/LKPracooWCF/Service1.svc/GetCommunicationDetailById } { status code: 400, headers {\n    \"Cache-Control\" = private;\n    \"Content-Length\" = 3319;\n    \"Content-Type\" = \"text/html\";\n    Date = \"Fri, 25 Sep 2015 15:45:14 GMT\";\n    Server = \"Microsoft-IIS/7.5\";\n    \"X-AspNet-Version\" = \"4.0.30319\";\n    \"X-Powered-By\" = \"ASP.NET\";\n} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.151.40/LKPracooWCF/Service1.svc/GetCommunicationDetailById
};
```

I have not found my custom error message!!!! Now if i test the same test case in **Advanced Rest Client Application** then i got my custom error messge like below.

```
Status - 400 Bad Request
<p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
<p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Invalid parameter found while fetching communication detail !'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
<p>......</p>
```

So what i want is how to handle this faultException `FaultException<FaultExceptionResponse>` at client (iPhone) side???.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your service is supposed to return Json but the exception is causing the response content-type to be text/html. You could drop using FaultException and switch to WebFaultException along with explicitly setting the content-type for the response. For example:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
var exception = new WebFaultException<string>(
    "{ \"Success\" = \"false\", " + 
    "\"ResponseString\" = \"Invalid parameter found while fetching communication detail !\" }",
    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
throw exception;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just extend the answer given by **MattC**. Big Thanks Matt. I'm posting this detail code as answer just for the future reader who'll come to this link in SO. One more thing, I have also written blog post in my blog - [krishnrajrana.wordpress.com](https://krishnrajrana.wordpress.com/2015/12/10/wcf-parameter-validation-using-iparameterinspector-in-wcf-rest-service/)

So guys here is how you handle exception at client (like iPhone devices Or android devices)

```
public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
{
    if (operationName == "GetCommunicationDetailById")
    {
        var model = inputs.FirstOrDefault() as TestViewModel;

        if (model != null &&
            (model.iConsultCommunicationID <= 0))
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
            var wfc = new WebFaultException<Response>(new Response(false, "Invalid parameter found while fetching detail !"), System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            throw wfc;
        }
    }
    else if (operationName == "AnotherMethod")
    {
        ............
    }

    // OR you can use switch case
    switch(operationName)
    {
        Case "Method":
            // your logic
    }

    return null;
}
```